# PHPMYADMIN ERROR: Unrecognized keyword

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, keyword

I have a problem regarding the following query:

```
SELECT idOrganizzazioni,ragioneSociale 
FROM organizzazioni
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/neo4j-community-3.1.0/import/organizzazioni.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

in particular, phpmyadmin generate this errors:

**Static analysis:**

11 errors were found during analysis.

```
Unrecognized keyword. (near "FIELDS" at position 162)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "TERMINATED" at position 169)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "BY" at position 180)
Unexpected token. (near "','" at position 183)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "ENCLOSED" at position 198)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "BY" at position 207)
Unexpected token. (near "'"'" at position 210)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "LINES" at position 216)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "TERMINATED" at position 222)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "BY" at position 233)
Unexpected token. (near "'\n'" at position 236)
```

I don't see what all the fuss is!
thanks!

Comment: Try moving `FROM` clause to the end, `SELECT idOrganizzazioni,ragioneSociale INTO OUTFILE 'C:/neo4j-community-3.1.0/import/organizzazioni.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM organizzazioni`;

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Does this command work in the MySQL command line client? Why not just use the phpMyAdmin "Export" feature instead?